# The input tensor should have dimensions 1 x height x width x 3. Got 1 x 3 x 224 x 224

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, onnx

I want to convert the Pytorch-trained model to the tensorflow model and use the model on mobile devices. For this, I follow these steps; First I convert the pytorch trained model to onnx format. Then I convert the onnx format to the tensorflow model.

Firstly pytorch trained model to onnx;

```
import torch
import torch.onnx
from detectron2.modeling import build_model
from detectron2.modeling import build_backbone
from torch.autograd import Variable

model= build_backbone(cfg)
model.eval()

dummy_input = torch.randn(1,3,224, 224,requires_grad=True)

torch.onnx.export(model,dummy_input,"drive/Detectron2/model_final.onnx")
```

Then onnx to tflite model;

```
import onnx
import warnings
from onnx_tf.backend import prepare

model = onnx.load("drive/Detectron2/model_final.onnx")
tf_rep = prepare(model)
tf_rep.export_graph("drive/Detectron2/tf_rep.pb")
```

```
import tensorflow as tf

## TFLite Conversion
# Before conversion, fix the model input size
model = tf.saved_model.load("drive/Detectron2/tf_rep.pb")
model.signatures[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].inputs[0].set_shape([1, 3,224, 224])
tf.saved_model.save(model, "saved_model_updated", signatures=model.signatures[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY])
# Convert
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir='saved_model_updated', signature_keys=['serving_default'])
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('drive/Detectron2/model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)

## TFLite Interpreter to check input shape
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test the model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
print(input_shape)
```

But when I use the model on mobile devices, I get the following error;

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Error occurred when initializing ImageSegmenter: The input tensor should have dimensions 1 x height x width x 3. Got 1 x 3 x 224 x 224.
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: reshape your input with numpy `reshape`

Comment: Pytorch Convolutional layer requires typically input of shape `(batch, num_channels, height, width)`,  in your case : (1, 3, 224, 224). However tensorflow requires input of shape `(batch, height, width, num_channels)` .  you need  to transpose your input to have a shape of (1, height, width, num_channels)

Comment: Just to be clear: do *not* reshape the input. You need to transpose it, as @Alka said.

Comment: @Alka
I got this error when I made the changes you said;
`dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 224, 224,3, requires_grad=True)`
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 7, 7], expected input[1, 224, 224, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 224 channels instead
@Berriel

Comment: I don't think you should modify the Pytorch to ONNX part, it seems already ok. However I see two potential candidate places for change? You can try first to change the shape in `model.signatures[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].inputs[0].set_shape([1, 3,224, 224])` to something  like `model.signatures[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].inputs[0].set_shape([1,224, 224, 3])`

Comment: If this doesn't work then you may need to apply the transpose operation in your mobile code, i.e. transpose your input image tensor so that it is shaped as (1, 224, 224, 3) before feeding it to your tflite model

Comment: @Alka Thanks for your help. But yes, unfortunately it didn't work.
`model.signatures[tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY].inputs[0].set_shape([1,224, 224,3])` throws this error; `ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 224. Shapes are [1,3,224,224] and [1,224,224,3].`
Do you have any reference for transpose operation?

Comment: I didn't really worked with tflite in java but rather in react-native. Nevertheless, I found this page https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/lite_support to contain lot of examples of image tensor transformations. maybe if you dig deeper into all available operations, you may be lucky to get Transpose there.

Comment: You may also check the tensorflow java binding https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java maybe they have the operations you need

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try `einops` for tensor transformations. It's elegant and powerful.
In your case, the code should be

```py
import einops
input_tensor = einops.rearrange(input_tensor,'b c w h -> b w h c')
```

Comment: I'm trying to convert onnx model to tensorflow and I'm facing same error, can you please give complete example how I can use einops.rearrange when I convert model ?